What is the right way to access a URL slug in nextjs >= 14 with the new App Router?
What is the correct way to access a slug using app router?
using page router (src/pages folder) it was normal to do something like this to access a slug in the URL params
/src
  /pages
    /[slug]
      /index.tsx


import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Page () {
  const router = useRouter()
  const slug = router.query.slug

  // rest code ...
}

but I dont believe this is an option anymore with App Router (src/app folder)
/src
  /app
    /[slug]
      /page.tsx


I believe I can extract the slug by splitting the pathname variable, but this seems like im not doing it "correctly" since I could just extract it out directly with the previous router
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

function Page () {
  // Get the current pathname
  const pathname = usePathname();
  
  // Split the pathname to get segments
  const segments = pathname.split('/');

  // Assuming the URL pattern is "/posts/[slug]", and you want to extract the slug
  // The slug would be in the second position after splitting (index 1), e.g., "/posts/my-first-post"
  const slug = segments[2]; // Adjust the index based on your URL structure

  return <div>Post Slug: {slug}</div>;
}


You can get this way
// src/pages/[slug]/index.tsx

export default function Page({ params }) {
  const { slug } = params;

  return <div>{slug}</div>;
}

